# Pandas DF Lookup - if value for record not available take the latest available

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and I've been trying to accomplish this task for a couple days now without success. In the beginning I had 3 dataframes that I was supposed to turn into only one with all the info. I managed to merge two of them correctly, which is now `df1`, however, for the third one there is a tricky logic that I couldnt figure out yet. The data structure is the following:

```
df1.head()
Out[12]: 
               Concat  YearNb_x  MonthNb_x  WeekNb_x NatCoCode VariantCode  \
1  BN2004384AAA112017      2017          1         1       AAA   BN2004384   
2  BN2004388AAA112017      2017          1         1       AAA   BN2004388   
4  BN2004510AAA112017      2017          1         1       AAA   BN2004510   
5  BN2004645AAA112017      2017          1         1       AAA   BN2004645   
6  BN2004780AAA112017      2017          1         1       AAA   BN2004780   

  Suppliercode_x       ModelName_x  SumOfVolume       Price  
1         HUAWEI          P9 (Eva)          745  399.991667  
2         HUAWEI  P9 lite  (Venus)         1770  211.666667  
4        SAMSUNG         A3 (2016)         6210  205.000000  
5          APPLE    iPhone 6s Plus            2  724.166667  
6        SAMSUNG  Galaxy J5 (2016)         4571  190.000000  

df2.head()
Out[13]: 
   YearNb  MonthNb  WeekNb NatCoCode VariantCode Suppliercode  \
0    2016        1       1       BBB   BN2001707        APPLE   
1    2016        1       2       BBB   BN2001707        APPLE   
2    2016        1       3       BBB   BN2001707        APPLE   
3    2016        1       4       BBB   BN2001707        APPLE   
4    2016        1       1       BBB   BN2002345      SAMSUNG   

           ModelName  LocalPrice ProductCategoryCode  
0          iPhone 4S       385.0                  HS  
1          iPhone 4S       385.0                  HS  
2          iPhone 4S       385.0                  HS  
3          iPhone 4S       385.0                  HS  
4  G. Note 2 (N7100)       395.0                  HS
```

All info except for the prices are supposed to be the same, what I need to do is **lookup for the prices (it can be by month, WeekNb can be ignored) in df2 for the same combination of items (NatCoCode, VariantCode, Supplier, Etc.) and IF the price for the respective month is not available df1 should take the LATEST available.**

I was trying the following logic, which obviously doesnt work:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('output2.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('localtest.xlsx')

def PriceAssignment(df1,df2):

    i = 1
    while i >= 5:
        for i in df1['VariantCode'], df2['BNCode']:
            if df1.loc[df1[i], df1['YearNb_x'], df1['WeekNb_x'], df1['NatCoCode'], df1['VariantCode']] == df2.loc[df2[i], df2['YearNb_x'], df2['WeekNb_x'], df2['NatCoCode'], df2['VariantCode']]:
                df1['LocalPrice'] == df2.loc['Price']
            elif df2['MonthNb']==12:
                df2['YearNb'] -= i
            else:
                df2['MonthNb'] -= i
    i += 1
    return df1
```

The output would be something like:

```
From:
    2017    2       OBE BN2004780BBB622017  SAMSUNG Galaxy J5 (2016)    500
    2017    2       OBE BN2005184BBB622017  APPLE   iPhone 6s Plus  300
    2017    1       OBE BN2005190BBB622017  APPLE   iPhone 7    350

    To: 
771 BN2004780BBB622017  2017    2   6   BBB BN2004780   SAMSUNG Galaxy J5 (2016)    67  171.9008264
772 BN2005184BBB622017  2017    2   6   BBB BN2005184   APPLE   iPhone 6s Plus  13  614.8760331
773 BN2005190BBB622017  2017    2   6   BBB BN2005190   APPLE   iPhone 7    1261    690.9090909

Result:
    771 BN2004780BBB622017  2017    2   6   BBB BN2004780   SAMSUNG Galaxy J5 (2016)    67  171.9008264 500
    772 BN2005184BBB622017  2017    2   6   BBB BN2005184   APPLE   iPhone 6s Plus  13  614.8760331 300
    773 BN2005190BBB622017  2017    2   6   BBB BN2005190   APPLE   iPhone 7    1261    690.9090909 350
```

**In this example, record 777 doesnt have a local price for the same month (03), in this case I would like to assign the latest available value to this item, in this case the latest value available for this item is from the month before, so this would be added in the LocalPrice column**

I was trying to check if there was an available price for the same item in the last five months (subjective). **The data (spreadsheets) can be found** [HERE](https://1drv.ms/f/s!ArJB-8QzupyMgYAF3lmBDTGj63BpZg)

Does anyone have an idea or know a proper way on how to perform such operation?

Comment: What you want is not very clear. Can you add an example?

Comment: I added a small example of the output, is that sufficient?